# Python Error: TypeError "argument of type 'type' not iterable

Tags: python, random

I am working on a school project where I have to generate a list of numbers with no repeats. The twist is I am not allowed to used `random.sample()` or `random.shuffle()`. I think I have found a way around it with my code except I get the error `TypeError "argument of type 'type' not iterable`. I have not been able to get around this so I need some help. Thanks for the help 
Here is the code:

```
import random
lis=[]

for i in range(5):
    rand=random.randint(1,10)
    if rand not in list: lis.append(rand)

print (lis)
```

Comment: In your if, `list` should be `lis`

Answer (score 0):

Misspell in `if rand not in list:`, should be if `rand not in lis:`

Here is working code:

```
import random
lis=[]

for i in range(5):
    rand=random.randint(1,10)
    if rand not in lis:
        lis.append(rand)

print (lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. Replace `if rand not in list: lis.append(rand)` with `if rand not in lis: lis.append(rand)`

Note list->lis

Answer (score 0):

Change `if rand not in list: lis.append(rand)` to `if rand not in lis: lis.append(rand)`

To tell you why?

- Checking `in` to a keyword `list` (which is not a iterable object)
- Typo :-)

So you must want to check in the `lis` list.